# View slide animation from bottom of the screen to top

Tags: titanium

I would like to animate a view.

I want the view to slide from the bottom to the top of the screen.

I wrote this code, but the view doesn't show up.

```
myWin.add(myView);
myView.height = '0%';
var expand= Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    height: '100%',
    duration: 300
});
myView.animate(expandView);
```

Reference is this [document](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation)

Answer (score 2):

@whitebear. In your problem, you want make the view slide to top from the bottom, but you had taken a wrong way. The way you had taken is a **Shape Change Animation**, which want to change the **height** of the view to make it. However it's will never get the **sliding** action you want, if your code work, what you will see is the **view** will get more and more bigger until fill the window, not a **sliding** action.

What you want is a **Position Change Animation** for the view. Just change the **top** value of the view can make it. Example:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: '-100%',             //the view can't be see at the bottom
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});

var ani = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    top: 0,                   //show the view from the bottom to top
    duration: 3000
});

view.animate(ani);
```

Just have a try, I hope this can help you. If you really want to change the height of the view to get the effect, maybe you can define a method to set the view height with the time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should call animate method of view passing it reference of animation object you created.

```
myView.animate(expand);
```

Comment: Thank you @Mushood , but it's my typo. I wrote animate() not add().  The problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For you requirement try this

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor : '#fff'});
var myView = Ti.UI.createView({backgroundColor : 'red'});
win.add(myView);
myView.height = '0%';
myView.bottom = '0'; // basically the view has been added at bottom of window

var expand= Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    height: '100%',
    duration: 1300
});
myView.animate(expand);// and you are only increasing the view's height in animate
```